# How to suppress correlation table in LME?

Tags: r, output, correlation, mixed-models

In the standard example of the lme() function in the nlme package of R:

```
fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)
summary(fm2)
```

there appears a correlation table:

```
Correlation: 
          (Intr) age   
age       -0.813       
SexFemale -0.372  0.000
```

which can be huge if there are many factor combinations involved.

**Is there any way to suppress the output in the summary command?** I know that I can use

```
   print(fm2, cor=F)
```

but this does not show me the rest of the usual output for example no p-value calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `nlme:::print.summary.lme` I don't see a way to suppress the correlation matrix printing (although you could create a hacked version of that function removing the `if` clause beginning `if (nrow(x$tTable)>1)` ...)

Perhaps it would be useful to you to be able to print *just* the summary of the fixed-effect parameters ... ?

```
 printCoefmat(summary(fm2)$tTable)
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps already (a bit). Sorry for the late upvote, I got distracted.

Answer (score 3):

Or, more concisely, `summary(fm2)$tTable`

Comment: this works, but `printCoefmat()` makes the output prettier/more like the summary output ...

Answer (score 3):

I just recently ran into the same issue when fitting models with lots of fixed effects and the correlation table was huge and really cluttered up the output. Looking at `print.summary.lme()` (which isn't exported, so you have to use `nlme:::print.summary.lme`) shows that the part comes from these lines:

```
if (nrow(x$tTable) > 1) {
    corr <- x$corFixed
    class(corr) <- "correlation"
    print(corr, title = " Correlation:", ...)
}
```

as already pointed out by Ben. Instead of rewriting/replacing the entire function, we can also use a simple trick, replacing `nlme:::print.correlation` (which is what is actually doing the printing of the correlation matrix) with our own `print` method for objects of class `correlation`. This can be done with:

```
assignInNamespace("print.correlation", function(x, title) return(), ns="nlme")
```

Now the correlation matrix will be omitted, but you get the remaining output.